# Update Server BIOS - Supermicro 5015A-EHF-D525

Tags: bios, supermicro

I've got a Barebone-Server with the Supermicro 5015A-EHF-D525 Mainboard.
Now I urgently need to update the BIOS to the newest version. Too bad I've never done that before and google isn't much help either.

I've downloaded the newest version of the BIOS and got the following 4 files:

- AFUDOS.SMC
- ami.bat
- Readme for AMI BIOS.txt
- X7SPA3.719

But now what? I read somewhere that I have to put this files on a bootable USB device? Is that true, and if so, how do I do it?

I also read, that I have to run the ami.bat with the X7SPA3.719 as a parameter on the device I want to be able to boot from later, but that didn't wokr either.

Since I really don't have to deal with that kind of problem often I'm pretty unexperienced so please try to explain it so even a newbie like I can understand it.

Thanks a lot in advance for your time and effort.
L Meier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, typically any file with the string "readme" in the name is a strong suggestion that you read the complete contents of that file.

Here it is, from X7SPA3_719.zip for that model of motherboard.

## FOR < filename>.zip

```
1. Save this file to your computer.

2. extract the files to a DOS bootable device (such as a bootable USB stick, or CD).

2. Boot to a DOS prompt and type AMI.BAT BIOSname.###.

4. Do not interrupt the process until the flashing is complete.

5. After you see the message of BIOS has completed the update, unplug the AC, clear the CMOS and plug in the AC and power on the system.

6. Go to the BIOS setup screen and press F9 to load the default and press F10 to save and exit.
```

If you don't know how to make a bootable floppy or USB device (or other media), I suggest that you start with Google and then come back if you try, and don't have any luck. The answer will be different depending on the operating system that you're using to prepare the device, for one thing. Since you haven't told us, I'm not going to research 2-4 different options for you.

You're supposed to come to here with at least a minimal amount of research done before asking questions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's the crux with Supermicro hardware. You need to run the BIOS update stuff from a Bootable device. This can be an USB stick, a Harddisk, even a CDROM if you do it right.

So:

1. Create a bootable device
2. Copy the BIOS files to it
3. Execute `ami.bat X7SPA3.719`